# Chrome Dev Tools highlights the wrong area for a pseudo-element's hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a weird issue where, when I hover on the pseudo element (`::before`) here, the highlight seems to be off.

[image: Screenshot]

The CSS given is:

```
.testimonial__quote::before {
      content: open-quote;
      font-size: 11.25rem;
      width: 4.0625rem;
      height: 3.4375rem;
      position: absolute;
      color: #fbce07;
      display: block;
      font-style: italic;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="testimonial__quote-container">
  <blockquote class="testimonial__quote">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean finibus lorem eu aliquet fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum
    primis in faucibus orci luctus.
  </blockquote>
  <p class="testimonial__author">- Scuderia Ferrari</p>
</div>
```

What am looking for is someone who has had an experience with this sort of issue. I can't post a JSFiddle as some people suggest, since it's not reproducible.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Please add a fiddle of some sort that shows the problem.

Comment: @JohannesPiontkowitz A fiddle will get this question closed just as fast. Markup and code **must** be within the question itself as text.

Comment: @Johannes This is not reproducible on fiddle, hence I can't link anything here.

Comment: @Rob he could add a Code Snippet, that way he has code **and** a sample.

Comment: The observed behavior looks like a bug. Check if it's reproducible in Firefox, Safari, Edge. Check if it's fixed in Chrome Canary, and if it happens in an older portable version of Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm It's reproducible on Firefox. So problem with my code am assuming..?

Comment: @JohannesPiontkowitz Yes he could. Just not a jsfiddle.

Comment: i always have the same problem, but i found a solution. i created a different css setting for chrome for that particular problem. and i use javascript to check if chrome browser, so my setting will be used .

Comment: @dean, FYI you can probably detect Chrome via `@supports` and some Chrome-specific property.

Comment: Yes, using javascript i can detect which browser  my website visitor is using, if chrome, load chrome.css  else load style.css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal behavior. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbctgyea/3/).
You set `width` and `height` for block element (in your case it is presented by `::before` pseudo element). But font-size of text is too big and symbol `"` "falls out" from sized container.

---

At the picture below I removed `width` and `height` properties. Now block sizes are calculated depending on block content (it is `"` symbol).

[image]

---

Add these styles to see that the character does not fit in the container:

```
overflow: hidden;
outline: 1px solid red;
```

[image]

---

So I think you should not set `width` and `height` to this element. Or you can use `svg` element or image with fixed sizes.

Comment: Hey man, thanks! 
This could potentially be the answer. I will check it out tomorrow morning!

Comment: OP is also setting `display: block` which forces the text to a new line.

Comment: @3rdthemagical A follow up question. Even on your fiddle, the blue hover doesn't cover the quotes completely even after removing the width and height. 
Also display : block causes issues? What can be the solution?

Comment: You need to read about fonts, here, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography) To have blue hover covers the quotes you need to use svg or image instead of typo symbol.

Comment: Thanks mate! 
It's a normal behavior expected of those characters.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this fiddle. Note: when you use `position:absolute` dont forgot to properties top, left, right, bottom,

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbctgyea/5/

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here within your answer, not a jsfiddle and never an image. A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead.

Comment: Thanks for the try man, but I think @3rdmagical's answer is accurate.